# vmError: Couldnt create thumb, file not found after update

Tags: sql, joomla, virtuemart

Hello I updated my Joomla from 2.5 to 3.5 and VM2 to VM3. Everything so far is working but in some products of VirtueMart I get this error vmError: Couldnt create thumb, file not found after update and when I click on the product I get this one:

YOU HAVE AN ERROR IN YOUR SQL SYNTAX; CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONDS TO YOUR MARIADB SERVER VERSION FOR THE RIGHT SYNTAX TO USE NEAR 'NATURA"" ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME DESC, `VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` DESC LIMIT 1' AT LINE 1 SQL=SELECT P.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID`, `L`.`PRODUCT_NAME`,`L`.PRODUCT_NAME FROM `#__VIRTUEMART_PRODUCTS` AS P INNER JOIN `#__VIRTUEMART_PRODUCTS_EL_GR` AS L USING (`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID`) LEFT JOIN `#__VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SHOPPERGROUPS` AS PS ON P.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` = `PS`.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` LEFT JOIN `#__VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` AS PC ON P.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` = `PC`.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` WHERE ( `PC`.`VIRTUEMART_CATEGORY_ID` = 1 AND ( `PS`.`VIRTUEMART_SHOPPERGROUP_ID`= "1" OR `PS`.`VIRTUEMART_SHOPPERGROUP_ID` IS NULL ) AND P.`PUBLISHED`="1" ) AND P.`VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID`!="78" AND `L`.PRODUCT_NAME <= "ΠΟΔΟΜΑΚΤΡΑ ΒΕΛΟΥΤΕ "NATURA"" ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME DESC, `VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ID` DESC LIMIT 1

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the ", i rename the product and now i don't get error on sql.